# Load/fadein HTML when page loads not working in IE 7 & 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

The following code works in safari, firefox, IE9 and chrome but in IE8 and 7 it just shows the loading image and never fades in the .wrap which has all the content. What could be wrong?

This is within the document ready function but even if I move it out of there it doesn't work.

```
   $(window).on('load', function() {

            var firstBackgroundImage = new Image();
                    firstBackgroundImage.src = "img/bg-img.jpg";        
                    firstBackgroundImage.onload = function () {
                        $('#loading-image').hide();
                        $(".wrap").fadeIn(300);
                        loadContent();
                    };
        });
```

CSS

```
 .wrap{
         height: 678px; 
         background: url("../img/bg-img.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
         margin-top:18px;
         padding-top:1px;
         position:relative;
         display:none;
    }
```

Comment: have you got window load event inside document ready?? you don't need to specify both; just use document ready. having both inside each other could easily lead to weird results.

Comment: great. I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you got window load event inside document ready? You don't need to specify both; just use document ready.

Having both inside each other could easily lead to weird results.